# Разряд имени существительного

Tags: морфология, существительные

Имя существительное — это часть речи, обозначающая предмет (субстанцию) и выражающая это значение в словоизменительных категориях числа и падежа и в несловоизменительной категории рода.

Существительные разделяются на несколько лексико-грамматических разрядов.

У какого слова принадлежность слова к определённому разряду имеет особенность и проявляется морфологически?

1)особняк

2)бедняк

3)тюфяк

4)середняк

5)скорняк

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это слово "тюфяк", неодушевленное существительное,примененное по отношению к живым существам и  приобретшая морфологические приметы одушевленности.

Другие примеры: дуб, пень. Все эти существительные неодушевленные, но когда они применяются для обозначения живых существ, становятся одушевленными.